# Location data is missing from GraphRequest (Android Facebook SDK)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to have my Android app fetch a logged in Facebook user's e-mail, birthday, and location. The first two fields can be retrieved successfully, but location is missing from the Graph API's response, and I can't figure out why.

I'm logging in with these permissions:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email", "user_birthday", "user_location"));
```

The GraphRequest is implemented as follows:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

            try {
                Log.d("jsonTest171", object.toString(4));

                String email = object.getString("email");
                UserData.emailAddress = email;

                String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                UserData.birthday = birthday;

                String location = object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
                UserData.location = location;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,location,birthday");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

The Facebook user has the app set to allow all 3 requested fields, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tytc.png).

This is the LogCat output from the debug line included in the above code:

```
{
    "id": "101936745620608",
    "email": "test77124@gmail.com",
    "birthday": "12\/20\/1983"
}
```

Why is the requested location field not present in the Graph response?

Comment: Have you verified that the user actually granted the permission to the app? (Debug the token, or call `/me/permissions` with it to verify.)

Comment: Yes, the user has allowed all the requested permissions. I double-checked with /me/permissions/ and user_location is set to granted.

Comment: Can you try the request in Graph API Explorer (using your app id), https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer - what's the result there? Does it show any debug messages?

Comment: Location is missing from that query as well. On the left side, the Location toggle is greyed out and says "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token". But I'm using the access token I got from the login result, which includes the user_location permission. What else could cause it to be disallowed?

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like it's any issue with the Android implementation. Using the link you provided, Location is disallowed for both my app and the Graph API Explorer, even though I have granted access to it for both. I assume I need to do something special for this type of permission, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In stead of `location` ask for `location{location}` in the Bundle parameters like:

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,birthday,location{location}");
```

The location part of the response looks like:

```
"location":{  
  "location":{  
    "city":"",
    "country":"",
    "latitude":0,
    "longitude":0 
  },
  "id":""
}
```

So you can retrieve them in your callback method like:

```
JSONObject location = object.getJSONObject("location").getJSONObject("location");
String city = location.getString("city");
String country = location.getString("country");
```